# Error in "cap production deploy" with assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, puma

I deploy my application rails with capistrano and I encounter an error when I type "cap production deploy". When I type this command at the beginning it works well but it is from assets: precompile that it bug

I have been looking for hours for solutions but none works.
I tried to change

```rb
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

To

```rb
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

In production.rb but no results.
The worst is that the name that the error shows me is no longer in my project

This is the error.

```
Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: name (CarouselTouchPlugin). To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true).
```

I'm so desperate aha I do not understand why it does not work
Here the full error message https://pastebin.com/FXaSF2iR

Comment: what is your Uglifier gem version?

Comment: gem 'uglifier', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.20'

Comment: this error can be misleading. It could also mean that there is some syntax error somewhere in your js code. If solution with `Uglifier.new(harmony: true)` not working, try to look for some syntax errors in js files maybe

Comment: I delete the file that is mentioned. I said it above so I have no error js. It's really weird